# Why wrapping words in span changes the text width?

Tags: html

In my application, I'm wrapping each word and whitespace with `span` tags. I do this on the fly, i.e. when the user loads the page I parse the content and wrap the words/whitespace. Pre-processing the HTML is not possible, because the amount of text can be big, and wrapping every single word/whitespace with span tags causes performance issues especially when running on mobile devices.

The problem is that wrapping word/whitespaces with span tags causes a slight change in the text width, which sometimes results in a word being shifted to the next line (an undesired behavior).

I have a sample code below, why the total width is different in these two cases (wrapping words/whitespaces with span tags VS plain text node)? Any way of accomplishing this without the text width being changed?

```js
const width1 = document.querySelector("body > p:nth-child(1) > span").getBoundingClientRect().width;
const width2 = document.querySelector("body > p:nth-child(2) > span").getBoundingClientRect().width;

document.querySelector('#result').appendChild(document.createTextNode(`Difference in widths: ${width1 - width2}px`));
```

```html
<p><span><span>This</span> phase</span></p>

<p><span>This phase</span></p>

<div id="result" />
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? On chrome 96 the difference in width is 0px.

Comment: That's odd, I'm on Chrome 97 and see a difference of 0.015625px

Comment: I also confirm there is a difference in widths on Chrome 97.

Comment: @Rafael are you zoomed in? Have you tried another browser?

Comment: I'm not zoomed in. Just tried it on Firefox and indeed there I get a 0px difference

Comment: The difference will change if you change your font-weight or family. In some font families it will be 0. I think this is because font is not monospaced font. Try it with monospaced font family.

Comment: @OnurGelmez why would that matter? it's the same string in both paragraphs

Comment: @OnurGelmez using a monospaced font solved this issue for me, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome but I don’t know why this happening

Comment: As a matter of fact, this changes from font to font. I've tried some non-monospaced fonts as well, and some of them behaved just fine.